# Animation for Group of Mesh in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am new to three.js. I have created multiple mesh and grouped by using JSONLoader. Now my problem is apply animation to that group or muliple mesh. Is it Possible to apply animation to that group in JSONLoader.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

To group files in threejs you'll want to create a Object3D():

```
 var group = new THREE.Object3D();
```

Then you'll want to add your meshes to this variable:

```
 group.add(mesh1); group.add(mesh2); group.add(mesh3);
```

Then lastly - you can animate this group in an animation loop:

```
 group.rotation.x+=.02;
```

It sounds like you just want to add your objects into a group var in your JSONLoader.load function.  If you can't figure it out feel free to share a jsfiddle of your code and I can point you to the right syntax.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I want to apply animation from morphTarget value in single JSON file. Is it possible multiple mesh animation from single JSON MorphTaget information. Please response your valuable answer.